# magento 2.4 contact form in custom phtml is missing captcha

Tags: magento2.4, contact-us, captcha

I'm trying to customize the Magento_Contact::form.phtml. In order to do this I've created an xml where I load my custom php and my custom phtml to show in lieu of the default files:

```
- Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\contact_index_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Vendor_Module::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Contact\ViewModel\UserDataProvider</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If I copy and paste the content of Magento_Contact::form.phtml into my Vendor_Module::form.phtml, everything shows correctly. But if I try to inject the original template in mine, then the form shows correctly but the captcha is missing:

```
- Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\form-phtml
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm")
    ->setTemplate("Magento_Contact::form.phtml")
    ->setName("contactForm")
    ->setViewModel($viewModel)
    ->toHtml()
;
```

I know the captcha is injected via observer in the original template, I don't know how to inject in my template, though. Is there a way to inject the default magento captcha in the template when it is called in another template?